# Getting command line arguments as tuples in python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, optparse

Here is an example of how I would like to call my script:

```
python script.py -f file1.txt "string1" "string2" -f file2.txt "string3" "string4"
```

Every file that goes as input will have 2 strings associated with that file. There can be any number of files.

To simplify, I am trying to get a print like this:

```
('file1.txt', 'string1', 'string2')
('file2.txt', 'string3', 'string4')
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import sys, os, traceback, optparse
import time
import re
#from pexpect import run, spawn

def main ():
    global options, args

    print options.filename

    #for filename in options.filename:
    #  print filename
      #f = file(filename,'r')
      #for line in f:
      #  print line,
      #f.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        start_time = time.time()
        parser = optparse.OptionParser(formatter=optparse.TitledHelpFormatter(), usage=globals()['__doc__'], version='$Id$')
        parser.add_option ('-f', '--file', dest='filename', help='write report to FILE', metavar='FILE', nargs=3)
        parser.add_option ('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', default=False, help='verbose output')
        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
        #if len(args) < 1:
        #    parser.error ('missing argument')
        if options.verbose: print time.asctime()
        main()
        if options.verbose: print time.asctime()
        if options.verbose: print 'TOTAL TIME IN MINUTES:',
        if options.verbose: print (time.time() - start_time) / 60.0
        sys.exit(0)
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e: # Ctrl-C
        raise e
    except SystemExit, e: # sys.exit()
        raise e
    except Exception, e:
        print 'ERROR, UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION'
        print str(e)
        traceback.print_exc()
        os._exit(1)
```

With the above script, I get only the second file and related strings:

```
('file2.txt', 'string3', 'string4')
```

Comment: I would appreciate if someone could help me with some code to achieve my goals (maybe using `argparse`). I tried understanding argparse, but couldn't figure out how to proceed. I would learn only if I am able to continue with my mini project. Right now I am stuck just at the argument parsing phase... Starting a bounty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you want to use the `action=append` argument of the `add_argument` method

```
import argparse

parser= argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument ('-f', '--file', nargs=3, action='append')

files = parser.parse_args('-f file1 string1 string2 -f file2 string3 string4 -f file3 string5 string6'.split()).file

for f in files:
    print tuple(f)
```

**gives you:**

```
('file1', 'string1', 'string2')
('file2', 'string3', 'string4')
('file3', 'string5', 'string6')
```

**Testing on cli:**

**with:**

```
import argparse

parser= argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='Test', usage='%(prog)s -f Filename Option1 Option2 ')
parser.add_argument ('-f', '--file', nargs=3, action='append')

files = parser.parse_args().file

for f in files:
    print tuple(f)
```

**results:**

```
python test.py -f file1 "foo bar" "baz" -f file2 foo bar
('file1', 'foo bar', 'baz')
('file2', 'foo', 'bar')

python test.py -f file1 "foo bar" "string2" -f file2 foo bar -f file3 "foo" "bar"
('file1', 'foo bar', 'string2')
('file2', 'foo', 'bar')
('file3', 'foo', 'bar')

python test.py -f file1 "foo bar"
usage: Test -f Filename Option1 Option2
Test: error: argument -f/--file: expected 3 argument(s)
```

Comment: This works for optparse too, so all you need is adding `action='append'` to `parser.add_option`.

Comment: & @Emilio - This works great on optparse. Thank you very much. Accepting this response.

Answer (score 1):

[argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) supports the notion of accumulators, which allow you to specify the same option more than once, which is probably more like what you want than anything `optparse` supports (your particular problem is that `optparse` doesn't know what to do with an argument specified multiple times, so it's "last one wins" at the command line).  `argparse` is included in Python 2.7 and 3.2, but you should be able to [download it](http://code.google.com/p/argparse/) for anything 2.6.x or later.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't very clear on your constraints, but this will work for any number of `-f`s and other flags

```
import getopt
import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]
tuples = []
while args:
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(args, "f:v", ["file", "verbose"])
    except getopt.GetoptError, err:
        print str(err)
        sys.exit(-1)    

    for o, a in opts:
        if o in ("-f", "--file"):
            tuples.append((a, args.pop(0), args.pop(0)))
        if o in ("-v", "--verbose"):
            print "yep, verbose"

print tuples
```

Comment: just did a test... this hangs on an incorrect input such as `-f file1.txt "string1" "string2" -f file2.txt "string3" --verbose "string4"`

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this similarly to the previous answer with a slight tweak:

```
import getopt
import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]
tuples = []
while args:
try:
    (opts, args) = getopt.getopt(args, "f:v", ["file=", "verbose"])
except getopt.GetoptError, err:
    print str(err)
    sys.exit(2)
```

Now you can either require input in the following way:

```
-f file1.txt,string1,string2
```

And parse it in the following way:

```
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ("-f", "--file"):
        tuples.append(tuple(arg.split(",")))
    if opt in ("-v", "--verbose"):
        print "yep, verbose"
print tuples
```

Or design the input as one string:

```
-f "file1.txt string1 string2"
```

and split on whatever strikes your fancy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `optparse` because you want to remain compatible with python 2.6, the `action='append'` solution works, too:

```
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-f', '--file', dest='filename', nargs=3, action='append')
```

#### Demonstration

```
>>> (opts, args)  = parser.parse_args("-f file1.txt string1 string2 -f file2.txt string3 string4".split())
>>> for fn_tuple in opts.filename:
...    print fn_tuple
('file1.txt', 'string1', 'string2')
('file2.txt', 'string3', 'string4')
```